# how to overwrite table nowrap attribute

Tags: html, css

In IE8 its working fine. In firefox if I remove the nowrap attribute from td text is getting wrapped properly but without removing nowrap text is not getting wrapped .

Is there any way to overwrite nowrap attribute through css in firefox.

```
<div style="width:100%;border:1px solid #eaeaea">
<table style="width:100%;word-wrap:break-word;table-layout:fixed" border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            thisssssssssssssssssssssssssss
        </td>
        <td nowrap="" style="word-wrap:break-word;">
            22222222thisssssssssssssssssssssssssss22222222thisssssssssssssssssssssssssss22222222thisssssssssssssssssssssssssss
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: nowrap="nowrap" to turn it off (it's deprecated - btw). Not using it will allow the wrapping you're going for `<td style=...`.

Answer (score 15):

```
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}

td {
 white-space: normal;
}
```

the white-space rule overrides the no-wrap attribute (your question), the word-wrap rule breaks unbreakable strings

Comment: The information about white-space overriding nowrap was very useful to me, great answer thanks!

Comment: Also found the whitespace override very useful. Thanks @clairesuzy

Answer (score 0):

A quick thought...before you look to overwrite FF. See what Chrome/Safari, etc. is doing, and consider overwriting that CSS with an  IE 8 conditional (a majority-rules approach).

`<!--[if IF 8]>...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your situation completely, but something like this might work a little better:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myDiv { width:100%; border:1px solid #eaeaea; }

    #myTable { width:100%; word-wrap:break-word; table-layout:fixed }
    #myTable th, #myTable td { border:1px solid #000000; }

    td.breakWord { word-wrap:break-word; white-space:nowrap; }
</style>


<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
    td.breakWord { white-space:normal; }
</style>
<![endif]-->


<div id="myDiv">
<table id="myTable" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            thisssssssssssssssssssssssssss
        </td>
        <td class="breakWord">
            2222222thisssssssssssssssssssssssssss22222222thisssssssssssssssssssssssssss22222222thisssssssssssssssssssssssssss
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

You can read more about conditional comments at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html